# Try to add new column into Posgres DB but only success when there is no data in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add new column into the table by 'rake db:migrate',but it return nothing in cmd.Then i try 'rake db:migrate:status' this time it return the following...

C:\Sites\seas>rake db:migrate:status

```
database: seas_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20160323084854  Create equipment
   up     20160329072332  Devise create users
```

Below is inside my migration file...

```
class CreateEquipment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :equipment do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :equip_id
      t.date :buy_date
      t.string :brand
      t.string :note
      t.date :exp
      t.string :status
      t.string :serial
      t.float :price
      t.string :pic_id
      t.string :ownby

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_column :equipment, :process ,:string
  end
end
```

This only happen if there exist some data in the table,otherwise migration work fine.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Where is the migration to add new column? Oh, I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
 add_column :equipment, :process ,:string
```

Table name should be in plural

```
 add_column :equipments, :process ,:string
```

But...  if the migration had already be ran, then it will not run again. Create a new migration

```
rails g migration add_process_to_equipments process
rake db:migrate
```

Ta dah!

Comment: I just create a new migration and Wow thats work, thank you.

Comment: Make also sure to delete that extra line you wrote in your first migration